# How to handle " *** glibc detected *** ./a: double free or corruption (top): " error for file handling function?

Tags: c, memory-management

I haven't used *Dynamic Memory Allocation*, and not freeing memory anywhere. It's even giving a double free error. Can any one please help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_EVENTS 1024 /*Max. number of events to process at one go*/
#define LEN_NAME 16 /*Assuming that the length of the filename won't exceed 16 bytes*/
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) ) /*size of one event*/
#define BUF_LEN     ( MAX_EVENTS * ( EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME )) /*buffer to store the data of events*/
#define SIZE 20000
int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
    int length, i = 0, wd;
    int fd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    time_t timer;
    char buffer2[25];
    char *s=NULL;
    struct tm* tm_info;

    FILE *fk;
    //char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
    char str1[] = "File has been updated at time :";
    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);
    strftime(buffer2, 25, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    fk = fopen( "/home/technoworld/Desktop/file.txt" , "w" );

    /* Initialize Inotify*/
    fd = inotify_init();
    if ( fd < 0 ) {
        perror( "Couldn't initialize inotify");
    }

    /* add watch to starting directory */
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, argv[1], IN_MODIFY ); 

    if (wd == -1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't add listen to %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Listening: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

    /* do it forever*/
    while(1)
    {
        i = 0;
        length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "read" );
        }  

        while ( i < length ) {
            struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
            if ( event->len ) {

                if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                        printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );       
                    else
                    {
                        printf( "The file %s was modified at %s \n", event->name, buffer2 ); 
                        fprintf(fk,"%s %s %c",str1, buffer2, '\n');
                    }
                }

                i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
            }
        }
        fcloseall(fk);
    }

    /* Clean up*/
    inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
    close( fd );

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to listen the change in file and writing the change in log file with time stamp.

Error:

```
Listening: /home/technoworld/Desktop/tmp/
The file .goutputstream-L3JTXW was modified at 2013:05:24 22:06:21 
The file .goutputstream-IRR4XW was modified at 2013:05:24 22:06:21 
*** glibc detected *** ./a: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x09438008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb7624ee2]
./a[0x80488bb]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75c84d3]
./a[0x80485c1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 558766     /home/technoworld/Desktop/a
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 07:00 558766     /home/technoworld/Desktop/a
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 558766     /home/technoworld/Desktop/a
09438000-09459000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7578000-b7594000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394123     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7594000-b7595000 r--p 0001b000 07:00 394123     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7595000-b7596000 rw-p 0001c000 07:00 394123     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75ae000-b75af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75af000-b7752000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7752000-b7753000 ---p 001a3000 07:00 394098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7753000-b7755000 r--p 001a3000 07:00 394098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7755000-b7756000 rw-p 001a5000 07:00 394098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7756000-b7759000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b776e000-b7773000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7773000-b7774000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7774000-b7794000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394076     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7794000-b7795000 r--p 0001f000 07:00 394076     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7795000-b7796000 rw-p 00020000 07:00 394076     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bfe5d000-bfe7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try to check if `fk` is opened.

Comment: If I write fclose(fk) just after completing while() then it does not give error.
In case I write it with close(fd) then It works but doent write on file!

Comment: @soon: Yes sir. It writes on the file one time and when next time file is modified then it gives error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included fclose(fk) after while(1) completes. It does not give any error and works fine on terminal. But in this case it does not write on file.txt.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_EVENTS 1024 /*Max. number of events to process at one go*/
#define LEN_NAME 16 /*Assuming that the length of the filename won't exceed 16 bytes*/
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) ) /*size of one event*/
#define BUF_LEN     ( MAX_EVENTS * ( EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME )) /*buffer to store the data of events*/
#define SIZE 20000
int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
  int length, i = 0, wd;
  int fd;
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];


    time_t timer;
    char buffer2[25];
    char *s=NULL;
    struct tm* tm_info;

  FILE *fk;
  //char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
  char str1[] = "File has been updated at time :";
    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);
    strftime(buffer2, 25, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
   fk = fopen( "/home/technoworld/Desktop/file.txt" , "w" );



  /* Initialize Inotify*/
  fd = inotify_init();
  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "Couldn't initialize inotify");
  }

  /* add watch to starting directory */
  wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, argv[1], IN_MODIFY ); 

  if (wd == -1)
    {
      printf("Couldn't add listen to %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Listening: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

  /* do it forever*/
  while(1)
    {
      i = 0;
      length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

      if ( length < 0 ) {
        perror( "read" );
      }  

      while ( i < length ) {
        struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
        if ( event->len ) {

          if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
            if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
              printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );       
            else
        {
                    printf( "The file %s was modified at %s \n", event->name, buffer2 ); 
                    fprintf(fk,"%s %s %c",str1, buffer2, '\n');
        }
          }

            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
      }

    }
fclose(fk);
  /* Clean up*/
  inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
  close( fd );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fcloseall` does not take any arguments.  (How did this even compile?)

Even if the initial `fopen` is successful (so that `fk` is not `NULL`), after the first trip through the `while (1)` loop, you will have called `fcloseall` and thus closed the file.  The `fprintf` to `fk` is thus printing to a closed file.  Since file operations allocate and use memory, and close operations free that memory, you are therefore using freed memory, hence the glibc error.

Comment: Depending on the options used at compile time, the incorrect call to `fcloseall()` would be compilable because it would use an implicit declaration of `int fcloseall()`. Feature macros have to be configured correctly for `stdio.h` to enable a prototype for `int fcloseall(void);`

Comment: fact that you're pushing a parameter on the stack where the function doesn't take one will not cause the segfault. ALSO he's not defining _GNU_SOURCE so fcloseall() is not even being declared irrespective of the fact that he's including stdio.h; even with that declared the SIGSEG won't disappear

Comment: Can you please suggest where should I place fclose(fk)??

Comment: I put fclose(fk) after  while (1) then it does not give error on give correct output in terminal. But it does not write on file.

Comment: The output to the file is buffered.  Add: `fflush(fk);` after the `fprintf` call to push the buffered data to the file.  (Otherwise, the data will show up when you fill a "block"—this size depends on the file system—or when you exit the `while (1)` loop, whichever occurs first.  Since there's no exit from the loop, you'll be waiting for a full block.)

Comment: Incidentally, the inner loop, with `i < length` as its control, advances `i` if and only if `event->len` is nonzero.  Should you encounter an event with a zero `len`, that loop will get stuck.  Presumably `i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len` should be outside the `if (event->len)` test.

Comment: I was trying to use freed memory. Putting fclose(fk) after use to fk is completed solved the error!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there because you are working on a 64 bit system and you are not including `time.h` and the return type from localtime(&timer) is being interpreted as a 32 bit integer rather than a 64-bit pointer (undeclared types default to int) ... You are losing the information in that implicit declaration.

Litmus test to see if I'm right:

declare the following right under the includes:

```
#include <limits.h>
struct tm;
struct timep;
struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
```

the SIGSEG will disappear  (although your code is still buggy)

The correct thing to do is to `#include <time.h>`

Comment: I included the time.h but no change!